# A phrase to claim the presence or existence of something or somebody

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

Suppose you live in a town near London. You always read/see/hear things about London. How can you claim the existence of your town in a phrase?

In spanish we can say "*Teruel existe*" and this phase has a strong affirmation that the town exists as itself and not as a small or irrelevant part of something greater. we look for some similar in english.

Comment: Please edit your question, as "reivindicate" is not an English word and the question therefore makes no sense. Perhaps you need to use an online translator to find an English equivalent for your word - or else, spend a paragraph explaining what the Spanish word means and how it is used.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a philosophy question. (How can you prove the existence of anything?) Can you clarify how it relates to English?